# how to add querystring values with RedirectToAction method?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, redirect

In asp.net mvc, I am using this code:

```
RedirectToAction("myActionName");
```

I want to pass some values via the querystring, how do I do that?

Answer (score 191):

Any values that are passed that aren't part of the route will be used as querystring parameters:

```
return this.RedirectToAction
  ("myActionName", new { value1 = "queryStringValue1" });
```

Would return:

```
/controller/myActionName?value1=queryStringValue1
```

Assuming there's no route parameter named "value1".

Comment: Agree, but action parameter with name "value1" could be present. Why not?

Comment: I think the answer meant "assuming there's no route parameter named 'value1'".  Otherwise the value would go into the route parameter's place in the generated URL, e.g. {controller}/{action}/{value1} would become /controller/myActionName/queryStringValue1 rather than /controller/myActionName?value1=queryStringValue1.

Comment: Levi is correct.  I've fixed the answer to clarify what I meant.

Answer (score 14):

For people like me who were looking to add the CURRENT querystring values to the RedirectToAction, this is the solution:

```
var routeValuesDictionary = new RouteValueDictionary();
Request.QueryString.AllKeys.ForEach(key => routeValuesDictionary.Add(key, Request.QueryString[key]));
routeValuesDictionary.Add("AnotherFixedParm", "true");
RedirectToAction("ActionName", "Controller", routeValuesDictionary);
```

The solution as you can see is to use the [RouteValueDictionary](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.routing.routevaluedictionary?view=netframework-4.8) object

Answer (score 4):

Also consider using [T4MVC](https://github.com/T4MVC/T4MVC), which has the extension methods `AddRouteValue()` and `AddRouteValues()` (as seen on this question on [setting query string in redirecttoaction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12180387/setting-query-string-in-redirecttoaction-in-asp-net-mvc/14266410#14266410)).

Answer (score 3):

Do not make the same mistake I was making. I was handling 404 errors and wanted to redirect with `404=filename` in the querystring, i.e. `mysite.com?404=nonExistentFile.txt`.

QueryString Keys cannot begin with numbers. Changing from `404` to `FileNotFound` solved my issue, i.e. `mysite.com?FileNotFound=nonExistentFile.txt`.

Comment: This isn't [generally true](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12465767/264628). It's also not true specifically for .NET MVC (at least in v5). Just remember that the keys are strings even if it consists only of numerals. You would access a numeric key as follows: `HttpContext.Request.QueryString["404"]`.

Answer (score 0):

If you already have a query string from somewhere, you can skip parsing and reassembling the query string and just use `Redirect` with `Url.Action`:

```
string queryString ="?param1=xxx&page=5";
return Redirect(Url.Action("MyAction") + queryString);
```

Answer (score 0):

Redirect("myAction/" + Request.QueryString);

Comment: Thank you for your interest in contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This question already has a few answers—including one that has been extensively validated by the community. Are you certain your approach hasn’t been given previously? **If so, it would be useful to explain how your approach is different, under what circumstances your approach might be preferred, and/or why you think the previous answers aren’t sufficient.** Can you kindly [edit] your answer to offer an explanation?