# How to pass mulitple querystring value in MVC 4

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, c#-4.0, query-string

I want to pass 7 querystring value from one ctroller to another controller action.

In my old applicaiton, I was passing these value into query string in URL.

Now, in MVC 4, please suggest me how i could include in "RedirecttoAction" or any other way ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1067200/how-to-add-querystring-values-with-redirecttoaction-method

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12180387/setting-query-string-in-redirecttoaction-in-asp-net-mvc/14266410#14266410

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can simply  pass parameters of action like this:

```
return RedirectToAction("Action","Controller", new {id=1,name="test",......})
```