# redirect to action and concate query string

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, redirect, asp.net-mvc-5.1

I have in a variable my query string

```
string queryString="tri=2&dd=3&order=4&.."
```

I need to redirect to action with my query string:

```
return RedirectToAction("Index", "call" new {queryString});
```

but i'm redirected to **call/index/queryString=tri=2&dd=3&order=4&..**

I need to be redirected to :

**call/index/tri=2&dd=3&order=4&..** 
 how can I do this please?

regards

Comment: You can use `var queryString = new { tri = 2, dd = 3, order=4 }` to build an object, and then `return RedirectToAction("Index", "call", queryString);`

Comment: i get the query string from the database, is a long querystring with 50 params or more, so that's i don't prefer to build the object

Comment: Why in the world are you storing query string in a database?

Comment: to save the options of a favorite of user we are storing his querystring. it's an old system

Comment: Possible duplicate of [setting query string in redirecttoaction in asp.net mvc](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12180387/setting-query-string-in-redirecttoaction-in-asp-net-mvc)

Comment: You can always build the url (e.g. `string url = Url.Action("Index", "call") + "?" + queryString;` and use `return Redirect(url);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try:

```
return Redirect("~/call/index/" + queryString);
```

Or

```
return RedirectToAction("index" + "/" + queryString, "call");
```

Comment: Hi! Code only answers rarely provide much insight for the OP and future visitors, a good answer usually includes some detais in what OP was doing wrong and what your code does and how it solves the problem.