# ASP.NET: Pass message from controller to view (ViewBag, ViewData or TempData)

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

## Situation

Inside my ASP.NET project, I have a view which allows the user to change his password. After submitting a form, the user will be redirected to the UserDetail using `RedirectToAction`. Here I want to notify the user if the password change was successful or not (planning to use [Alertify JS](http://alertifyjs.com/)). Yet, I can't seem to successfully pass the message from my controller to my view.

How does one properly pass data (simple string) from a controller to a view when using `RedirectToAction` without the use of `ViewBag`, `ViewData`, `Tempdata`, ...? Or, if there's a way to solve my current difficulties with these, happy to hear.

1. **`ViewBag`/`ViewData`**: Can't be used since I return `RedirectToAction` where I can't pass it in the URL instead of a `View`. I've considered using `Ajax` to return `JSON` instead of using `RedirectToAction` which would enable me to use `ViewBag` but this brings in some difficulties and would change the overall structure of the project.
2. **`TempData`**: I don't have a `session` configured in my `Startup.cs` and can't do so since I'm missing the `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Session` namespace. I also can't add the namespace since this adds some complications. See the following error: `System.TypeLoadException: 'Method 'ConfigureAppConfiguration' in type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.WebHostBuilder' from assembly 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting, Version=1.0.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60' does not have an implementation.'`

I'd rather not work with cookies or some sort of cashing system.
**EDIT:** I'd also rather not use a querystring but seeing the comments/answers makes me realize that my options are limited. I forgot to add the querystring/route param to the list earlier.

#### The ManageController.cs

```
[HttpGet]
public IActionResult UserDetail(int id)
{
    // Code to GET the UserViewModel
    return View(model);
}

[HttpGet]
public IActionResult UserPassword(int id)
{
    // Code to GET the UserViewModel
    return View(model);
}

[HttpPost]
public IActionResult UserPassword(UserViewModel model)
{
    // Code to check and save the password.
    if (user.Password == model.Password) {
        //ViewData["Message"] = "Succeeded";
        //TempData["Message"] = "Succeeded";
    } else {
        //ViewData["Message"] = "Failed";
        //TempData["Message"] = "Failed";
    }
    // TODO: Alert the user
    return RedirectToAction("UserDetail", new { id = model.UserId });
}
```

#### UserDetail.cshtml

```
<!-- Some view code -->
<form>
    <button class="ui button button-back" type="button" onclick="window.location.href = '@Url.Action("UserPassword", "Manage", new { id = Model.UserId })';">Change Password</button>
</form>
<!-- Trying to use ViewData -->
@*<div id="id-message" data-value="@ViewData["Message"]"></div>*@

<script>
  $(document).ready(function () {
    console.log("Ready");

    // Alert the user of a password change
    //var message = $("#id-message").attr("data-value");
    //var message = "@(TempData["Message"] as string)";
    if (message !== null && message !== "") {
      alertify
        .alertmessage, function () {
          alertify.message('OK');
        };
    }
  });
  // Some script code
</script>
```

Comment: Add a `string Message` property to you view model

Comment: You can pass it as route parameter `new { id = model.UserId, message= "" }` and accept it in `UserDetail(int id, string message)`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to add querystring values with RedirectToAction method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1067200/how-to-add-querystring-values-with-redirecttoaction-method)

Comment: Thank you all for your comments. I'd rather not use a querystring/route parameter but it seems like my options are limited. I've got one more question about the change to the model though @StephenMuecke, Even if I changed the model, I'm not actually passing it to the YserDetail, right?

Comment: But this is not about "from my controller to my view", you want to pass data from request123 to request231. Keeping and managing state is always a pain on the Web, pick your bitter medicine. On how many servers do you want to run the site?

Comment: @WouterVanherck, If you have passed the message (or a `bool` indcating success or otherwise, you can just set the value of `Message` in `UserViewModel` before passing it to the view

Comment: `I'd rather not use a querystring/route parameter` Can you talk us through why not? I ask since this is is a pretty standard PRG pattern.

Comment: @bommelding It's more of a web app then a site, which could be run on a lot of devices. I presume you ask that question so you could recommend the best option?

Comment: @mjwills I'm still learning ASP.NET and am trying to write uniform code. Since this is only a string, it's not a big deal to pass it through an URL but when passing objects that can't be put in the model comes into play, it's gotta be done in a different way, shouldn't it?

Comment: I'd use a `bool` rather than `string`, but that is a side issue. What kind of object are you envisaging that need to be passed through a querystring that can't be put in the model?

Comment: @mjwills I might be missing the entire point but I'm not actually passing the model from UserPassword POST to the UserDetail GET, just the Id for navigation right? I'm a bit confused with the flow now

Comment: @WouterVanherck I would rather consider fixing the TempData issue than asking this question because if u would have TempData fixed u would have some many options to implement. I would find a good solution if TempData does function correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass it as route parameter with `RedirectToAction()` method

```
return RedirectToAction("UserDetail", new { id = model.UserId, message= "" });
```

and accept it

```
[HttpGet]
public IActionResult UserDetail(int id, string message)
{
   // Code to GET the UserViewModel
   return View(model);
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to pass it without putting the message in the URL?

Comment: Then you have to use `ViewBag`, `ViewData` or `Tempdata` which you don't want

Comment: Accepting this answer because there doesn't seem to be another option besides `TempData` when using `RedirectToAction` and it might help others with similar situations

Answer (score 0):

About another options as your described, i would suggest SessionState:

```
string passwordChange = "Password has been changed";
Session["yourName"] = passwordChange  // inside your if else logic calling it from your UserDetail controller method.
```

Or creating a JsonResult result to reference an Ajax call, for instance.

Comment: Can you elaborate on how this would solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

change:

```
[HttpGet]
public IActionResult UserDetail(int id)
```

to

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult UserDetail(UserViewModel model)
```

Add the Message property to your model.

should do it for you